# Shadowed identity in cryptography

Tags: authentication, authenticated-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, modular-arithmetic

I was trying to implement zero knowledge protocol for authentication based on the paper "[A Practical Zero-Knowledge Protocol Fitted to Security Microprocessor Minimizing Both Transmission and Memory](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45961-8_11#page-1)".

In that, the first step is…

> each security device with identity $I$ receives an authentication value $B$ (The inverse of $A$ modulo $n$) computed by some authority from $A=J^{1/\mu} mod\ n$, where $J$ is the **shadowed** identity $I$

Also, they have defined “shadow” as…

> **Shadow**: One first completes a short message (half the length of a public modulus $n$) with a similar sized redundancy, named **shadow**, then extracts the $\mu^{th}$ root of this element in the chosen ring based on the composite integer $n$.

From my point of view (being a programmer), I do not understand what this “shadow” is and how to calculate it.

Also there is a sentence…

> then extracts the $\mu^{th}$ root of this element in the chosen ring based on the composite integer $n$

How I set the value of $\mu$? Can I take any arbitrary value? What is the significance of that value?

> Also there is a step $t=r.B^d\ mod\ n$. This means $(r.B^d)\ mod\ n$
>   or $r.(B^d\ mod\ n)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GQ identification scheme is essentially a zero-knowledge proof of a value $x$ such that $x^\mu \equiv J \pmod N$ where $N$ is an RSA modulus and $(\mu,N)$ are system parameters and $J$ is known to the verifier and $x$ only known to the prover.

Now your question is not directly concerned with the aforementioned proof where a user shows the possession of a credential, but with how credentials are issued to users by the authority.

Before going into the questions regarding the GQ identification scheme, I briefly recall existential forgeability of textbook RSA signatures.

Recall the RSA setting where we have an RSA modulus $N=pq$ being the product of two primes $p$ and $q$ and the public exponent
 $e$ being an invertible element of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ (with order $\phi(N)$) and the private key $d$ it's multiplicative inverse, 
 i.e., $d \equiv e^{-1} \pmod{\phi(N)}$. Now we may abuse the notation and write $d:=1/e$ (what is done in the GQ paper).

So, in texbook RSA signatures the computation of a signature for a message $m\in \mathbb{Z}_N$ amounts to computing 
 $\sigma \equiv m^d \pmod{N}$ and verification amounts to checking $m\equiv \sigma^e \pmod{ N}$.

Observe, that by simply choosing $\sigma$ and computing the message $m$ as $m:= \sigma^e {\mod N}$ gives an existentially 
 forged message signature pair $(m,\sigma)$ for the textbook RSA signature.

Observe, however, that the adversary cannot 
 control the message $m$, since the adversary cannot predict what $\sigma^e$ will yield (consequently, it is a good idea to apply a cryptographic hash function $H$ to messages before signing, since then such an existential forgery would yield $H(m)$ and one would need to find $m$ which is firstly hard given a secure hash function and moreover will very likely not yield a meaningful message $m$ anyways. This is called the **hash then sign** paradigm).

**Shadowed Identity**

Now, exactly this is the purpose of a shadowed identity in GQ, i.e., we require the credential including identity $I$ to have some structure and thus the identity is **shadowed** to $J$. 
 Consequently, it is not efficiently possible to choose a random element $A$, compute it's $\mu$'th power ($\mu$ is the public key $e$ from above) and obtain a valid shadowed identity $J$. 
 Note, that one could choose $A$ randomly and compute $J\equiv A^\mu \pmod N$, but requiring $J$ to have 
 some defined redundancy (being an shadowed identity), 
 such a forgery will not lead to a valid identity $J$ under the redundancy scheme with very high probability.

Note that this prevents an adversary from computing a credential on its own without interacting with the authority (knowing the value $1/\mu$). The authority, however, can form the shadowed identity $J$ and then compute $A\equiv J^{1/\mu} \pmod N$. Observe that this is essentially a textbook RSA signature of the authority for message $J$.

Nevertheless, it is not exactly stated in the paper how this shadow should be chosen.

**Extracting $\mu$'th roots**

Note that $\mu$ plays to role of $e$ (the public exponent) in the RSA setting and note that computing the inverse $1/\mu$ from $(\mu,N)$ 
 (which is equivalent to the private exponent $d$ in the RSA setting) requires to know the factorization of $N$. Observe that 
 $1/\mu$ is computed as the multiplicative inverse of $\mu$ modulo $\phi(N)$ using the extended euclidian algorithm.

In the GQ identification scheme as described in their paper, the factorization of $N$ is only known to some authority and thus the identification tokens $A$ can only be computed by this party. Consequently, having this redundancy scheme (**shadowed identities**) and limiting the knowledge of the private key $1/\mu$ and the factorization of $N$ to some authority, $\mu$ and $N$ can be system parameters for many users.

The value $\mu$ can be chosen to be any value that is co-prime to $\phi(N)$ and for instance fixed to the prime $2^{16}+1$ as it is common in the RSA setting.

**Last part of the question**

You write

> Also there is a step $t=r.B^d\ mod\ n$. This means $(r.B^d)\ mod\ n$
>   or $r.(B^d\ mod\ n)$?

It means $(r\cdot B^d)\ mod\ n$ and this is equivalent to $(r\cdot (B^d mod\ n))\ mod\ n$.

**Final remark**

Finally, I would like to suggest to read about the GQ identification scheme in another source such as chapter 10 of the freely available [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), since the description is much easier accessible than in the original paper.

Comment: What is the recommended method for calculating shadow?

Comment: The method of choice to prevent such issues in practice is to use a hash function (as in the hash then sign paradigm). In this context you would compute the shadowed identity $J$ as being the hash value of the identity information. A widely used real world example for RSA signatures is for instance the encoding used in [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](http://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf).

Comment: One last question. There is an equation in the text "$s_A=(J_A)^{−s}mod\ n$". How could I calculate that? Taking $(J_A)^{−s}$ and taking mod n?

Comment: I assume you refer to the chapter in the handbook of applied cryptography. You compute the value of $-s$ as $\phi(n)-s$, i.e., $-s$ is the additive inverse of $s$ in the group of order $\phi(n)$ and thus $\phi(n)-s$. Then you can use any fast exponentiation algorithm of your choice to compute the value $s_A$ by raising $J_A$ to the power of $\phi(n)-s$. Clearly, since you are working in $Z_n$ the value $s_A$ is in $Z_n$ and thus you always reduce modulo $n$, i.e., when doing multiplications and exponentiations.

Comment: Using the same example from the text, when I took $modularpow(J,phi−s,n)$, I am getting the value as -126739. I have J=34579, phi= 419184, s=233875 and n=420491

Comment: Strange, even when adding $n$ to make it positive your result is wrong :/ However, I do not know your implementation. A quick check using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=34579%5E%28419184-233875%29+mod+420491) shows that it should be correct.